# What's the downside of choosing <Yes> in resolvconf's configuration dialog?

Tags: virtualbox, resolv.conf

An automatic restart by its Windows host has somehow messed up my Ubuntu (12.04 lts) VirtualBox's resolvconf.  (For one thing, `/etc/resolv.conf` is gone.)

Therefore, I ran

```
% sudo dpkg-reconfigure resolvconf
```

...upon which I am presented with the following dialog:

```
The resolvconf package contains the infrastructure required for dynamic updating of
the resolver configuration file. Part of the necessary infrastructure is a symbolic
link from /etc/resolv.conf to /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf. If you choose this
option then this link will be created; the existing /etc/resolv.conf file will be
preserved as /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/original, and will be restored if this
package is removed.

Declining this option will prevent future installations from recreating the
symbolic link and therefore the resolver configuration file will not be dynamically
updated. Dynamic updating can then be activated following instructions in the
README file.

The presence of resolvconf can affect the behavior of other programs, so it should
not be left installed if unconfigured.

Prepare /etc/resolv.conf for dynamic updates?

                         <Yes>                       [<No>]
```

(Note that the  option is the one selected by default.)

My question is:

> Can someone explain to me what are the downsides to choosing `<Yes>`?

(I understand the downsides to choosing `<No>`, but I don't see the downsides to choosing `<Yes>`, though I have to assume there are such downsides, otherwise it's hard to understand why I'd be given the choice in the first place.)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use resolvconf (which an Ubuntu user normally does) then you normally choose Yes here. Choose No only if you want to install resolvconf but not activate its control of the glibc resolver. Some people do this for special reasons that I need not go into here.

The question was originally added in order to try to remain in compliance with Debian policy which is very fussy about what packages may do to configuration files.

The default answer should be Yes. If the default answer is No in your case and you don't know why, then ask a question about that or file bug report against resolvconf.