# How to troubleshoot slow web browsing in Ubuntu VBox guest (Windows host)?

Tags: networking, virtualbox, dpkg, dns

I have an Ubuntu 12.04 LTS VirtualBox guest running on a Windows 7 host.  Until recently it had been working flawlessly<sup>1</sup>.

Since a few days ago, however, web browsing in this Ubuntu VBox has been extremely slow (so much so that many pages never finish loading).  This sluggishness is confined to the Ubuntu VBox; I experience no slowdown at all in the Windows host.  (This rules out server-side problems and problems with the internet connection.)

I have reason to believe that the problem has to do with the Ubuntu VBox's DNS resolution, because the sluggishness started right after I had to run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure resolvconf`.  I posted a [question](https://askubuntu.com/q/333834/124738) about this at that time.

That said, I can't figure out what I could have broken by doing this, since, besides answering 'Yes' in the `dpkg-reconfigure resolvconf` dialog (described in that [earlier question](https://askubuntu.com/q/333834/124738)), I did not make any other changes to my DNS resolution configuration.

In any case, it was after doing this `sudo dpkg-reconfigure resolvconf` and rebooting the Ubuntu VBox, that I noticed that web browsing had become, on average, very slow.

A typical experience is that, using Firefox (for example) I do a Google search (which is usually reasonably quick<sup>2</sup>), then I click on any one of the top hits, and then the looong wait begins.  This wait is long enough that, *before it's over*, I have time to switch to the Windows 7 host, repeat the same Google search (using Firefox again), click on the same hit that I'd just clicked while in the Ubuntu guest, instantly retrieve the desired, read whatever I needed to read, and switch back to the Ubuntu guest.  (If nothing else, this confirms that whatever the problem is, it is confined to the current configuration of the Ubuntu guest.)

> How can I troubleshoot this problem further (and hopefully fix it)?

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> As an aside, let me express my admiration for VirtualBox.  Wow, what an impressive piece of software!</sub>
<sub><sup>2</sup> Interestingly, the first few Google searches I did after reconfiguring `resolvconf` and rebooting were slow-as-molasses, but eventually they got faster.  My guess is that (consistent with my suspicions of the current DNS setup) this observed speed-up is due to caching of some key IP addresses.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

OK, I found an (excellent) answer to my question, [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/272574/124738).

It turns out that the only non-comment line in my `/etc/resolv.conf` file was

```
nameserver 127.0.0.1
```

...which coincides with the situation presented in that other [thread](https://askubuntu.com/q/272358/124738).

In my case, the problem was resolved by performing only the first adjustment suggested in that answer, namely:

1. run `gksudo gedit /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`;
2. comment out the `dns=dnsmasq` (→ `# dns=dnsmasq`);
3. run `sudo service network-manager restart`.

Comment: You are possibly a victim of this bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/dnsmasq/+bug/1003842